# generalization and specialization

Tags: database-design

This might be simple one but I am finding it very difficult to work around it.

I have got 3 tables like; `Employee`, `manager`, `supervisor` in here `manager` and `supervisor` is the specialization of the table `employee`. Now I have got another table say `Project` which should have 1 manager and 3 supervisor.

How do I put this in my mysql database?

As `Employee` has `Employeeid`, `name`, `position` and `manager` will have `employeeid` as pk and fk sme with `supervisor` which will have `employeeid` as pk and fk. How do I put the data in manager and supervisor table? Do I use a view?

How would mysql know which is manager and which is supervisor?

Comment: Is being a manager (or a supervisor) a per-project or a per-employee property? In other words, can the same employee have different "roles" in different projects, or a manager is the manager on all projects?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### How to connect your tables:

You can make an additional table `ProjectMember` with the following columns:

```
employeeId
projectId
role
```

Where role can be 'manager' or 'supervisor'.

So, if these are your `Employee`s:

```
employeeId    name
1             Mark
2             Steve
3             Simon
4             Stan
```

And this is your `Project`:

```
projectId    name
1            Project X
```

Then the `ProjectMember` table can have the following rows:

```
employeeId projectId role
1          1         manager
2          1         supervisor
3          1         supervisor
4          1         supervisor
```

To get the names of all members of Project X you can then use the following query:

```
SELECT emp.name AS name, pm.role AS role
FROM ProjectMember pm
JOIN Employee emp
ON pm.employeeId = emp.employeeId
WHERE pm.projectId = 1
```

This will return:

```
name   role
Mark   manager
Steve  supervisor
Simon  supervisor
Stan   supervisor
```

### Adding specializations

If there is any specific data for a `Manager` or a `Supervisor` as specializations of `Employee`, then you can retrieve the additional data as follows.

Suppose Mark is a `Manager`, then this can be a row in `Manager`:

```
employeeId clearanceLevel
1          10
```

**EDIT**: To store a `Manager`, you first store an `Employee` and get its (probably generated) `employeeId`. How to get a generated id depends on the database system you are using (see [this on MySQL](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/getting-unique-id.html)). Then you store a row in `Manager` with that same `employeeId`.

To get this additional information, while you do not really know who is in the `Manager` table on beforehand, you can use a `LEFT JOIN` to retrieve data from optional additional tables (they may or may not be there, but you still want to get the basic queried rows):

```
SELECT emp.name AS name, pm.role AS role, mgr.clearanceLevel AS clearanceLevel
FROM ProjectMember pm
JOIN Employee emp
ON pm.employeeId = emp.employeeId
LEFT JOIN Manager mgr
ON mgr.employeeId = emp.employeeId
WHERE pm.projectId = 1
```

This will return:

```
name   role       clearanceLevel
Mark   manager    10
Steve  supervisor NULL
Simon  supervisor NULL
Stan   supervisor NULL
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for the quick feed back .. now as the manager is specialization of employee how do I fill the manager table with the employee id and clearance.. as employeeid on manager is fk from the employee and  pk for the manager

Comment: Both `employee` and `manager` can have the same primary key: `employeeId`. In case of a `manager`, its `employeeId` also serves as foreign key to `employee`. For example, Mark has a row in `employee` with `employeeId=1`, but also a row in `manager` with `employeeId=1`.